# Probably broken install of gdal: gdalUtils

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, rgdal, proj

I am attempting to use `gdal_translate`, I directed the gdal path using `gdal_setInstallation()` because I have several Gdals on my machine. Yesterday this worked, today it is not and I am not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#When I go to set the installation I get this
gdalUtils:: gdal_setInstallation(search_path =  "C:\\Users\\user\\Gdal\\gdalwin32-1.6\\bin\\", rescan = T)
Probably broken install of gdal at 'C:/Users/user/Gdal/GDALWI~1.6/bin/'

#And when I run this next line of code I get a response I do not understand 
sid2tif <- gdal_translate(src_dataset = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\S2L Project\\GIS ProjectClipping\\Orthos\\2013 Orthos\\0_3.sid", dst_dataset = "0_3.tif", of ="GTiff", output_Raster = T)
Error in current_match & driver_match : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types


#My Environment Variables/System Variable matches = "C:\\Users\\user\\Gdal\\gdalwin32-1.6\\bin\\"
```

I am trying to figure out gdal_translate() before I move on to use batch_gdal_translate.

Thank you!!

Comment: I would suggest getting `gdal_translate` working at the windows command line first before attempting to run the R wrapper provided by `gdalUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody comes across this, I managed to figure it out, maybe it could help.

I have 5 versions of gdal and 3/5 of them do not have the MrSID plugin that I need to convert a .sid file. I found out which versions have this plugin by using the cmd prompt, `gdalinfo --format MrSID`. Using a version that has the MrSID plugin, I was able to direct it to the correct path via `gdal_setInstallation()` which allowed `gdal_translate()` to work. I added this path to my System Variables path.